# How to obtain the remaining energy from BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER

Tags: android, battery

I'm trying to get the energy consumption of my phone. I'm doing as follows but the result is 0 while I was specting any amount of nanowatts per hour.

```
    int status2 = mBatteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER);
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNT should be retreived using getLongIntProperty